# Get Facebook friends list from Session

Tags: android, facebook

I am developing a code for get facebook friends list using android. I have active Session (facebook). Can i get the friends list from the Session? If not, What is the easy way to do this?

I am using facebook sdk 3.0

Answer (score 0):

You can query the graph once you acquire basic permissions.
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=xxxxxx

Comment: i am trying to get Accesstoken using this  

Session.getActiveSession().getAccessToken()   but it does not return any thing

Answer (score 0):

As Facebook Hackbook example, If You have a active session of Facebook object the use given code to get the list of Friends

```
this.dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "",
                    "Please Wait", true, true);
            String query = "select name, current_location, uid, pic_square from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()) order by name";
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("method", "fql.query");
            params.putString("query", query);
            Utility.mAsyncRunner.request(null, params,
                    new FriendsRequestListener(context,  
                            this.dialog));
```

FriendsRequestListener class

```
    class FriendsRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener {
        private Context context;
        private String graph_or_fql;
        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        public FriendsRequestListener(Context context , ProgressDialog dialog) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.context = context;
            this.dialog = dialog;
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
            dialog.dismiss();

            jsonArray = new JSONArray(apiResponse); 
            // this is the response of the Friend list in json format, set the jsonArray to List.

        }

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
            dialog.dismiss();

             Toast.makeText(context, "Facebook Error: " + error.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

In *onComplete* of *FriendsRequestListener* class you can get the jsonArray of Friends List.
Hope this is work-full/helpful for you

Comment: I have active Session but it is not open. how can i open that session

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the Request class, specifically the [Request.newMyFriendsRequest](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Request#newMyFriendsRequest%28Session,%20GraphUserListCallback%29) method.